# Insert values from multiple elements with PHP into a database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I need to save the data within these page elements into a database - they will be dynamically created by the user, but always in a similar format

The HTML appears:

```
<div><p>1</p>
   <div><p>Broccoli</p></div>
   <div><p>Carrot</p></div>
</div>

<div><p>2</p>
   <div><p>Chicken</p></div>
   <div><p>Beef</p></div>
   <div><p>Lamb</p></div>
</div>
```

values needed from this:

```
"1:Broccoli", "1:Carrot", "2:Chicken", "2:Beef", "2:Lamb"
```

(happy to add classes/IDs to any divs to extract the required values)

What should happen:

1. On click of a save button, data is scraped into an array (via
   Jquery?)
2. Array is sent to PHP file and inserted into the database

Any help on this would be great, thanks

Comment: if they're dynamically created for example by javascript just save the options as they add them into an array. then serialise the array and dump it into a hidden input field then your php page can read->unserialize->insert array element by element into the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should save this data to the database as the user is creating it. not try to scrape your own page afterwards. This is going o save you a lot of time and make your script run faster.

Once you've done that, you can use `serialize()` to convert your array into a string that you can store in a database, and then turn the string back into an array with `unserialize()`

Comment: Thanks I will have to have a go at doing this.